# parse_str wrongly parsing integers to strings

Tags: php

Consider the following PHP code:

```
//JS
// var a = { category: [9] };
// var x = $.param(a);
// window.location.href = "test.com/?foo=" + x;

$x = $_GET["foo"];
$x = "category%5B%5D=9"; // this is what $_GET["foo"] looks like
$result = array();
parse_str($x, $result);

var_dump($result);
```

Now, that will output:

```
array(1) {
  ["category"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "9"
  }
}
```

Which is wrong. The element inside the `category` array should be an integer and not a string. Why is `parse_str` handling that input so badly? And how can I make it convert to string only the data that is between `"` or `'`? (pretty much how `json_decode` works)

Comment: There's no data typing in URL syntax, so everything is considered a string.

Comment: It's not like JSON, which has different syntax for numbers from strings (it puts quotes around strings).

Comment: @Barmar Yes, that was a typo. I should use JSON then, but can I use it with `GET` petitions? Is there some "json to url" way to convert that data?

Comment: You can just pass urlencoded JSON into `foo=` then call `json_decode()` on `$_GET['foo']`.  Validate it cautiously though to make sure it includes only what you expect (you should do that if using `parse_str()` too)

Comment: Why is this an issue? PHP will automatically convert strings to numbers when you use them in arithmetic operations.

Comment: @Barmar `when using them in arithmetic ops` <--- that is the issue. I'm not using them in any arithmetic ops.

Comment: Then why is it a problem that it's a string? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Barmar I'm saving those values in a database

Comment: If it's MySQL, it will automatically convert as well. If not, use PHP's type conversion function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using plain GET, how should `parse_str()` know about the desired data type? You, the programmer, need to:

- verify input values (is it really numeric?)
- cast values to the data type you wish. `parse_str()` will always deliver strings.

If you want to transfer strictly typed values between the client and the server, you need to go a more sophisticated way . Starting from json, over XMLRPC to SOAP.

Using json in the request might be the simplest way to start, however it does not fit well for `GET` requests since it is hard to type that in an url, sure you do that by code, however I still think `json` doesn't suite for GET requests.

Comment: I realized that `$.param()` won't add quotes to values such as `"9"` (not an  int but a string containing a number). Everything said from there is pointless, I should have used plain JSON from the start.

Comment: Yes indeed, using json or even xmlrpc or soap would be an alternative if you want to transfer strictly typed values. Let me add that to the answer...